# NextJS not reading environment variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS app which is running Next.js v12.2.5, but it doesn't seem to be reading environment variables.

I have created a `.env.local` file which has:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:3001
```

And my next.config.js is:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['react-daisyui'])
module.exports = withTM({
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    images: {
        domains: ['placeimg.com'],
    },
    env: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL,
    },
})
```

In one of my component's index.tsx file, I'm doing the following:

```
const apiURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL

console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL)
console.log(apiURL)
```

On the server once I do `npm run dev` and go to the route on Chrome, I get the following for my log statements:

```
undefined
undefined
```

And on the browser I get:

```
trips:1          GET http://localhost:3000/trips 404 (Not Found)
```

Note my NextJS is on `http://localhost:3000` and my Express backend which I'm trying to connect to is on `http://localhost:3001`

Why is NextJS not reading the environment variables I have set?

Comment: Remove this `env: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL,
    },`

Comment: what about setting in .env.development?

Answer (score 0):

You can try, dotenv. remember to install the package 'npm i dotenv --save'

Then create a .env file on your src folder and type down the info like

db=POSTGRES

id=ALAN

password=fjord

Once you do this, you'll be able to have access to the info by doing something like

const id = process.env.id

BY THE WAY.. Importing dotenv to the file you're using is not done
import * from 'dotenv'  < This is bad

Should be imported like this
require('dotenv').config()